# Understanding and tracing Apache error: Wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache

I have struggled to understand exactly what this recurring entry in my apache error log is saying. It happens at irregular intervals from less than 1/hr to a couple in 1 minute.

```
        SELECT wp_em_events.post_id FROM wp_em_events
        LEFT JOIN wp_em_locations ON wp_em_locations.location_id=wp_em_events.location_id
         WHERE (`recurrence`!=1 OR `recurrence` IS NULL) AND ( event_start_date >= CAST('2015-03-16' AS DATE) OR (event_end_date >= CAST('2015-03-16' AS DATE) AND event_end_date != '0000-00-00' AND event_end_date IS NOT NULL)) AND (Array) AND (`event_status`=1) AND (`event_private`=0)
        GROUP BY wp_em_events.post_id ORDER BY event_start_date ASC
        LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
     made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, WP_Query->parse_query, do_action_ref_array, call_user_func_array, em_ical_item, em_locate_template, include('/plugins/events-manager/templates/templates/ical.php'), EM_Events::get
```

It assume it is being caused by https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/

I have not encountered any front-end manifestations of this error. I do however believe it is impacting mysql performance. Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I have come across SQL queries being output in apache log files like that before but I would first disable the plug-in to see if that stops the error output and if performance increases.

Then I would start to look through the Events Manager forum articles to see if anyone else has had a similar issue. I had a quick glance but couldn't see anything, the link is https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/events-manager. Perhaps even post on those forums as you might get some better assistance there.

If that doesn't help at all then digging into the plug-in code and searching for that specific SQL query should turn up the part of the code that is causing the entry in the error log and then from there you can attempt to debug the error and find out why it is happening, I can't help on that much more I am afraid without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The plugin developers have not been particularly helpful, I have search extensively for people who have encountered similar issues and have not found anything. From some basic tests I have performed in the past, I did not see any significant difference in performance with the site disabled. I still need to test if the error occurs with the plugin is deactivated (however I am fairly confident it will not).

What should I search for in the code? The full code is available in the plugin repository.

Could you help me understand what this error is saying in layman's terms?

Comment: I have finally got a chance to do some digging into this plugin and I found the location that the SQL gets built and runs from classes/em-events.php line 80. It basically builds up an SQL query and runs it to get the events, the WHERE conditions are built dynamically. Have you tried running that SQL to see if it has an error at all as that might give some clues as to what is going wrong. I expect the error is being generated because the query failed, not 100% certain on that one though.

Comment: In response to your edit, it could be that category is bugged in some way and is causing the SQL query to fail, I imagine it will most likely be the WHERE clauses that the problem is creeping in. Try creating a new category and see if the problem persists, or try deleting the broken category and re-creating it and see if you still get the problem.